# How to stop creepers blowing up my Zombie XP farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a zombie spawner that I have turned into an XP farm.

[image]

The problem that I have is that creepers spawn in the zombie spawning area, and end up at the bottom of the 22 block glass chute. Then, because there are a lot of zombies I don't realise there is a creeper, and it blows me, and the chute, up.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Don't use glass.  If the creeper can't see you, it won't blow up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whole design:

[image]

Close up of changes:

[image]

Here you end your chute with a half slab on a hopper and a half slab at eye level (2 the underneath of the block 2 higher than the hopper. Because the creeper cannot track to you, even when you hit it it will not blow up. To be safe, I wear a golden chestplate with blast protection (that I got from the zombies) and I build the end of the chute out of Obsidian.

Here is an image of my solution in MC:

[image]

You can see the half slabs (cobble) and the chute (glass, at the top - it doesn't join because of the creepers and lack of sand near me). Under the base slab is the hopper with chest:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think all these elaborate solutions are necessary. This is a very simple farm that should work just fine.

From your diagram, I don't see a way for a creeper to spawn, unless they're spawning right at the bottom of the drop. Light up the bottom well enough so they can't spawn in there and you should be fine. Mobs don't spawn in water, so if the floor is all water under the spawner, you should be all set.

Comment: They are spawning in the area with the water - or possibly part way down. The bottom is well lit - I have a lava pool covered in glass near it and I don't want to light higher up because that will slow down the zombie spawning rates.

Comment: Mobs don't naturally spawn in the air, only when spawned by a spawner. As to the spawning rates, you are at least 22 blocks away from the spawner. Any light generated by the lava can't reach more than 16 blocks away. You could have a torch right inside the bottom of the chute and it wouldn't affect spawning rates at all.

Comment: Again, mobs don't spawn in water or air. The only possibility is on a solid block at light leve 7 or below.

Answer (score -1):

Do `/gamerule MobGriefing false`. That will stop them from blowing it up. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: I'm not asking for a cheat here...

Comment: That's the only way I know then.

Comment: That's fine, but it wasn't the answer I was looking for - don't worry, you don't have to answer *every* question that you see here...